# Is there an entrance exam I can take to get admitted directly into a European PhD program in electrical engineering without a masters?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, exams, europe

I'm an undergraduate electrical engineer. I have studied up to 80 percent of a masters in electrical engineering program and have two IEEE published papers. Is there such a thing as a PhD entrance exam that I can take to prove my ability to pass advanced electrical courses and get admitted directly into a PhD in a university in Europe?

Answer (score 2):

Admission and funding in European PhD programs depends a lot on the university and the country's regulations. You should search for the programs you are interested in applying to and read their specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In Germany, it is possible to start your PhD without a master [since 2000](http://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/veroeffentlichungen_beschluesse/2000/2000_04_14-Bachelor-Master-Promotion.pdf) (text only in German). You have to find an advisor and pass a qualifying examination, which differs by university. So, you first have to choose where you want to do your PhD.

Comment: i want to do my phd at eth zurich or eindhoven institiute of technology

Comment: i wanted to do my phd at eth zurich its great to know you are there

Comment: can you provide me with your mail to contact you i really have many question regarding eth zurich and i need your help.

Comment: I did my PhD at ETH Zurich but had a diploma, so I don't know anything about their qualifying examinations or if they even offer this opportunity.

Comment: thanks for your response but i asked your mail cause i had questions about accomdation in zurich and if igot enrolled in masters

Comment: how will i cover my costs ? do i work as a teaching assitant or i have to find a job outside eth

Comment: You can find this information online: https://www.ethz.ch/en/the-eth-zurich/working-teaching-and-research/welcome-center/employment-contract-and-salary/salary.html There might have changed a lot since I left ETH but at least I can tell you that you don't need an additional job.

Answer (score 0):

The Dutch (eg. Eindhoven) situation is that a PhD is normally funded (or done as an external PhD with a company). As such anyone will have to go through what amounts to a "job" interview. Within the system a masters is normally expected, but exceptions can be made, especially for candidates from countries where a masters would not be required to start a PhD.

A PhD in The Netherlands will always have a full professor who will function as promotor (under whom's responsibility you would work). You may in addition have a daily supervisor with less experience. You will basically need to convince your interviewers that you can do the research. A common question would be for you to present your Msc thesis (or bsc thesis) as an example of your ability to write, the papers you published could be a good alternative, especially if you were the main (or only author). Be prepared to answer the question why you didn't finish the masters (in this case time can be in your benefit)

Answer (score 0):

In Spain it is in general necessary to have an "Oficial" Master's degree to enter a PhD program. The "official" qualifier means that some master's programs are formally recognized as conduits to doctoral programs, whereas others are not. In general a foreign degree would have to be recognized as equivalent to a Spanish degree, usually by the administration of the university offering the doctoral degree. Although there are lots of qualifications to this general statement, applicable in special cases, basically you need to have a master's degree already. [Here](https://www.ucm.es/requisitos-de-acceso-doctorado) and [here](http://www.ucm.es/informacion-adicional-para-alumnos-con-estudios-extranjeros-1) is information (in Spanish) about the requirements at the Universidad Complutense de Madrid, which is probably typical. For someone who does not have an official Spanish master's degree or a foreign degree recognized ("homologado") as such, there is a process to apply for admission, but the details probably depend on the particularities of the applicant.

Admission and funding are generally separate matters. The summary with respect to funding is that there isn't much, what there is pays poorly by the standards of northern Europe or the US, and it's competitive to get what little there is.

Answer (score 0):

In France, they count it in years of study. My Bachelor in Engineering was 5 years, so that was "equivalent" to a MS in France. I had an MS as well, but I didn't even bother ($) translating it, because it wasn't necessary.